# updating 3 image fields

Tags: php, mysql, image, field

I'm running into the following problem:

I've a client area where my client can edit 3 image fields.
The problem is:

I just want to update the photo name in the database for the fields that are not empty.
So, for example, if my client decide to change photo #2, I need a mysql update that will not override photo #1 and #3.

I could write a lot of "if" statements but I think there's a better way to do it.

any help?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use an array and a `foreach` statement. It could be something like:

```
$field = array();

$field['1'] = $_POST['field1'];
$field['2'] = $_POST['field2'];
$field['3'] = $_POST['field2'];

foreach($field as $value){
    if($value != NULL){
        // Update the MYSQL database for the field using $value to figure
        // out which field the script is on
    }
}
```